# ibus(unicode vietnamese) not working with skype

Tags: skype, ibus, unicode

i install ibus (unicode vietnamese) in ubuntu 16.04 but only skype not working. chrome or facebook it ok. Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

Some snap apps (Slack, Skype, Rocket.Chat+, Telegram) from Ubuntu Software seems can't type Vietnamese by ibus, while other may (Viber, Postman, PHP Storm, Chromium).
I reported this issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus-unikey/+bug/1803270
Following Olivier Tilloy (osomon), maybe these apps (the snap apps can't type Vietnamese) do not use the desktop helper.

A temporary solution is download Skype deb packet from Skype official website and you can type Vietnamese in this by ibus.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install skype by **.deb** file from web, not from ubuntu software center. This is link:

https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/

I can use ibus-unikey to type Vietnamese on this version.